# Context root in Glassfish and domain name

Tags: eclipse, servlets, glassfish

Coming from a Microsoft background with mostly experience in IIS, I'm having difficulty in understanding some fundamental concepts when it comes to using Glassfish and publishing apps using domain names. I am using Java EE 7, Glassfish 4 and Eclipse Kepler running on Windows Vista.

When I run the Glassfish admin console, I notice under Applications, you can set the "Context root" for the app. So in Eclipse, if my project is called com.mycompany.myapp, the context root would be /com.mycompany.myapp

If I then type in the following url in my browser, I get the html content:

```
http://localhost:8080/com.mycompany.myapp/default.html
```

What I really want is to use a domain name. So the url above should look like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/default.html
```

It isn't clear to me what I have to do to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

The context root is only the context part of the URL, it can't change the server part of the URL. In general, if you want a public URL to point to some web application, you need something which maps the URL to the real URL of your application server. This has in most cases nothing to do with the backend side but with the configuration of a load-balancer (e.g. Apache) or proxy in front of your application server. This may also be hosted by an external provider.

Anyway, you can change the context root for applications on GlassFish either via the admin GUI or you can add a glassfish-web.xml in your WEB-INF dir which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">

        <glassfish-web-app error-url="">
            <context-root>/your_desired_context_root</context-root>
        </glassfish-web-app>
```